# regex that doesn't include 5555555555

Tags: regex

Regex still confuses me. I've got `^[2-9]\d{9}$` that matches a valid telephone number (digits only). How do I also make it exclude '5555555555'? Thanks.

Comment: Validating telephone numbers is rarely useful in practice. Example: Suppose my "work" number is +44 (0)20 1234 5678 ext 3142? Did your validation expect an extension? Most fail to allow for all sorts of things that are 1% issues...but 1% is a **lot**. Accept anything, ask the user to double-check it, and move on to your next task.

Comment: Thanks for the info ... but I'm only accepting home U.S. based numbers ...

Comment: When I lived in the U.S., I would have written (415) 123-4567 and been mildly cross if a form required me to write 4151234567 instead, as it's harder to read and therefore harder to make sure I typed it right. Also: Who says home numbers can't have extensions? :-) Some people use Asterisk for exactly that, mostly to screen out nuisance calls and separate family calls from other kinds (for instance, to ignore non-nuisance calls from companies in the evening, but take calls from family). Why prevent people giving you their correct information?

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative lookbehind:

```
^[2-9]\d{9}(?<!5555555555)$
```

[<sup>Regex101</sup>](https://regex101.com/r/3e7GSt/1)

... or a negative lookahead, if you prefer:

```
 ^(?!5555555555)[2-9]\d{9}$
```

[<sup>Regex101</sup>](https://regex101.com/r/MZMmQd/1)

Comment: Careful, in that some regex engines don't support lookbehind at all.

Comment: Do some engines also not support lookahead?

Comment: @testing123 - Lookahead has been in JavaScript for years. Lookbehind was only added in ES2018.